# Part of raster disappears when zoomed in using ArcGIS Online

Tags: raster, arcgis-online, tiles

I exported my raster in a tile package to use within ArcGIS Online and it worked but when I zoom in the bottom part gets cut off and disappears. I think the issue has to do with the extent or something along those lines but I can't seem to figure out why this is happening or how to fix it. I really have no idea where to look or what I should even be looking for.